# Template files used in the manual book Officeverse

Tags: templates, officedown

I'm learning `officer` and `officedown` packages by reading the manual book [Officeverse](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/index.html). However, I couldn't find the template files such as `templates/templates_demo.docx` to reproduce the examples.

I was wondering, are these templates available?

Your kind guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: I'll add links to download them, meanwhile you can download the resulting files (when a given template is used), download all the content, and it will be the same as the original template.

Comment: Thanks, @David. Understood. For `officedown`, using the resulting file as the template can just reproduce the result. However, for `officer`, using the resulting file as the template, the new result will actually append the template. Right?